# Create functions in gnuplot

Tags: function, gnuplot

I am reading data from a file, and I determine the min and the max.

I would like to implement a function where if min==max, then min = 0

I have thios so far:

```
reset

# Define two helper functions
ismin(x) = (x<min)?min=x:0
ismax(x) = (x>max)?max=x:0

# Initialise the 'global' vars
max=-1e38
min=1e38

plot "Data.txt" u 0:(ismin($3)*ismax($3))

#set terminal windows
set terminal png medium size 900,600
set output "Data.png"

print min
print max

iseq(min,max) = (min == max)?min = 0 :0

print min
print max
```

How can I set min to 0 if min==max?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

How about an `if` statement:

```
if (min == max) min = 0
```